# Split a dataframe or matrix into multiple parts using assign in a loop

Tags: r, matrix, split

i have a matrix, consisting of monthly values from 2004 to 2018. i would like to split and save these into the individual years with the corresponding months. Like this

...

```
Sigma.ma2004 <- Sigma.ma[1:12,]
Sigma.ma2005 <- Sigma.ma[13:24,]
Sigma.ma2006 <- Sigma.ma[25:36,]
Sigma.ma2007 <- Sigma.ma[37:48,]
Sigma.ma2008 <- Sigma.ma[49:60,]
Sigma.ma2009 <- Sigma.ma[61:72,]
Sigma.ma2010 <- Sigma.ma[73:84,]
Sigma.ma2011 <- Sigma.ma[85:96,]
Sigma.ma2012 <- Sigma.ma[97:108,]
Sigma.ma2013 <- Sigma.ma[109:120,]
Sigma.ma2014 <- Sigma.ma[121:132,]
Sigma.ma2015 <- Sigma.ma[133:144,]
Sigma.ma2016 <- Sigma.ma[145:156,]
Sigma.ma2017 <- Sigma.ma[157:168,]
Sigma.ma2018 <- Sigma.ma[169:180,]
```

...

I tried to create a loop for it.

...

```
start_var <- seq(from = 1 ,to = 169, by = 12)
end_var <- seq(from = 12, to = 180, by = 12)

for (i in 1:length(start_var)){
  for(j in 2004:2018){
    assign(paste("Sigma.ma",j,sep=""), Sigma.ma[start_var[i]:end_var[i],])
  }
}
```

...

The individual parts are saved, but all with the same strange values.

where is the mistake?

Comment: Remove the ```j``` loop and makes a ```years <- 2004:2018``` variable that you use in the ```assign``` call as ```years[i]```.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating multiple objects in global environment, you could store the data in a list. You could convert the matrix into dataframe and then use `split`

```
df <- as.data.frame(Sigma.ma)
temp <- split(df, gl(nrow(df)/12, 12))
```

This will give you list of dataframes which you can access using `temp[[1]]`, `temp[[2]]` and so on.

Using a reproducible example,

```
mat <- matrix(1:100, 10)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)

split(df, gl(nrow(df)/2, 2))

#$`1`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
#2  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92

#$`2`
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#3  3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
#4  4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
#....
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
years <- 2004:2018

for(i in 1:length(years)) {

  start_row <- (i - 1) * 12 + 1
  end_row <- start_row + 11

  assign(paste0("Sigma.ma", years[i]), Sigma.ma[start_row:end_row, ])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `sapply()` over `assign()` like below:

```
sapply(2004:2018, function(k) assign(paste0("Sigma.ma",toString(k)),Sigma.ma[(k-2004)*12 + (1:12),]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to convert your matrix into a 3D array.

```
n_years <- 3
start_year <- 2004
n_rows <- 5

set.seed(123)
Sigma.ma <- matrix(sample(100, n_years * n_rows * 12, replace = T), nrow = n_rows)

array(Sigma.ma, dim = c(n_rows, 12, n_years))
```